# unable to uninstall module from DNN 7

Tags: xml, module, dotnetnuke, uninstallation, dotnetnuke-7

When trying to delete a module from DNN 7 I am getting this error. Would anyone know how to start debugging this or where this error would be generated at:

> Error: is currently unavailable.
>   DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.ModuleLoadException: Unexpected end
>   tag. Line 95, position 13. ---> System.Xml.XmlException: Unexpected
>   end tag. Line 95, position 13. at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg) at
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent() at
>   System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument.LoadFromReader(XmlReader reader,
>   XmlSpace space) at System.Xml.XPath.XPathDocument..ctor(TextReader
>   textReader) at
>   DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.Installers.PackageInstaller..ctor(PackageInfo
>   package) at DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.Installer..ctor(PackageInfo
>   package, String physicalSitePath) at
>   DotNetNuke.Modules.Admin.Extensions.UnInstall.UnInstallPackage() at
>   DotNetNuke.Modules.Admin.Extensions.UnInstall.cmdUninstall_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Answer (score 0):

Turns out some intrusive data was injected in the Packages table, specifically in packages.manifest. Therefore, the module couldn't not perform the uninstall without a pristine manifest structure.

All that was required was to rebuild the xml structure.